# JavaScript Object.defineProperty doesn't work as expect

Tags: javascript

I mistakenly used `Object.defineProperty` by pass a function as its descriptor param, just like blow code:

```js
let fakeDesc = () => {}
let obj = {
  method1: function() {
    console.log('this is method1');
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'method1', fakeDesc);
obj.method1();
```

the code evaluated result is that `method1` is not overrided.

according to the MDN doc(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> If a descriptor has neither of value, writable, get and set keys, it is treated as a data descriptor.

so I think that the `fakeDesc` should be treated like a data descriptor, and the default `value` property should be `undefined`, so the above code would result in `obj.method1` equal `undefined`.

How about this situation? and is there some document can explain this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The passed descriptor (the third argument) is supposed to be a *plain object* with properties like `value` and `writable`. If you pass a *function* instead of an object, it gets ignored.

> A data descriptor is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable.

If you pass a function, you're not passing a data descriptor.

If you pass an object with a `value` property of your `fakeDesc`, it'll work as expected:

```js
let fakeDesc = () => {}
let obj = {
  method1: function() {
    console.log('this is method1');
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'method1', { value: fakeDesc });
obj.method1();
```

When you pass an object without a `value` property, the underlying value won't change, although the *descriptor* on that property may change. For example, the following changes `enumerable` to `false` on `method1`, despite not changing the underlying value (of the `this is method1` function):

```js
let obj = {
  method1: function() {
    console.log('this is method1');
  }
};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'method1'));
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'method1', { enumerable: false });
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'method1'));
```

I suppose you could *technically* pass a function and have it change the descriptor, but you would have to set a property *directly on the function*, which is really weird:

```js
const fakeFn = () => {};
fakeFn.enumerable = false;
let obj = {
  method1: function() {
    console.log('this is method1');
  }
};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'method1'));
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'method1', fakeFn);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'method1'));
obj.method1();
```

When MDN says that the default values for the different keys (like `configurable` and `enumerable`) are `false`, and the default value for `value` is `false`, it's referring to the process *when you create a property that doesn't exist on the object already*. The process is defined in [DefineOwnProperty](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.9).

Comment: which part in the document says `If you pass a function instead of an object, it gets ignored.`?

Comment: See the [docs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.5) - passing a function is just like passing an empty object. The passed function (or object) has no keys that `ToPropertyDescriptor` understands, so nothing happens as a result.

Comment: I knew how to use defineProperty, I just wonder if passing a function as descriptor will cause ignored, and if all JavaScript engine treat this situation by a same standard?

Comment: Yes, the specification requires it. Unless the function has any of the [keys](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.5) expected on the passed object (as in edit), no changes will occur as a result of passing the function.

Comment: so when the default value will be used?

Comment: It looks like the default values described on MDN are values that are set for the value/descriptor *if no property with that name exists on the object yet* - otherwise, if the property already exists, the "default values" aren't considered, and it just tries to update the *current descriptor* with any new properties that exist in the passed descriptor.